# Comment out sections of text that correspond to certain IDs listed in another file

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, grep

Can someone help me out with this. I have 2 files

First one contains IDs of employees that left a company

`employeeid.txt`

```
5678D956 
45S87954
56898K78
4D856898
556987F8
23657D87
```

Second file is a config file for an application that stores users settings

`App.conf` (only part of the file)

```
/export/home/conf[naa.5678D956]/displayName = "John Paul (naa.5678D956)"
/export/home/conf[naa.5678D956]/Scripts = "true"
/export/home/conf[naa.5678D956]/FTP = "true"
/export/home/conf[naa.5678D956]/HomeDirs = "true" 
/export/home/conf[naa.4487984D]/displayName = "Cara Jones (naa.4487984D)"  
/export/home/conf[naa.4487984D]/Scripts = "false"
/export/home/conf[naa.4487984D]/FTP = "true"
/export/home/conf[naa.4487984D]/HomeDirs = "true" 
/export/home/conf[naa.45S87954]/displayName = "Eimer Fenton (naa.45S87954)"
/export/home/conf[naa.45S87954]/Scripts = "true"
/export/home/conf[naa.45S87954]/FTP
/export/home/conf[naa.45S87954]/HomeDirs = "true"
/export/home/conf[naa.56898K78]/displayName = "Edd Waters (naa.56898K78)"
/export/home/conf[naa.56898K78]/Scripts = "true"
/export/home/conf[naa.56898K78]/FTP = "true"
/export/home/conf[naa.56898K78]/HomeDirs = "true"
/export/home/conf[naa.909878S4]/displayName = "Phil Mooney (naa.909878S4)"  
/export/home/conf[naa.909878S4]/Scripts
/export/home/conf[naa.909878S4]/FTP = "true"
/export/home/conf[naa.909878S4]/HomeDirs  = "true"
```

I would like to have it so that if a employee ID exists in `employeeid.txt`, it comments out their configuration setting in `App.conf` and saves as new file

```
#/export/home/conf[naa.5678D956]/displayName = "John Paul (naa.5678D956)"
#/export/home/conf[naa.5678D956]/Scripts = "true"
#/export/home/conf[naa.5678D956]/FTP = "true"
#/export/home/conf[naa.5678D956]/HomeDirs = "true" 
/export/home/conf[naa.4487984D]/displayName = "Cara Jones (naa.4487984D)"  
/export/home/conf[naa.4487984D]/Scripts = "false"
/export/home/conf[naa.4487984D]/FTP = "true"
/export/home/conf[naa.4487984D]/HomeDirs = "true" 
#/export/home/conf[naa.45S87954]/displayName = "Eimer Fenton (naa.45S87954)"
#/export/home/conf[naa.45S87954]/Scripts = "true"
#/export/home/conf[naa.45S87954]/FTP
#/export/home/conf[naa.45S87954]/HomeDirs = "true"
#/export/home/conf[naa.56898K78]/displayName = "Edd Waters (naa.56898K78)"
#/export/home/conf[naa.56898K78]/Scripts = "true"
#/export/home/conf[naa.56898K78]/FTP = "true"
#/export/home/conf[naa.56898K78]/HomeDirs = "true"
/export/home/conf[naa.909878S4]/displayName = "Phil Mooney (naa.909878S4)"  
/export/home/conf[naa.909878S4]/Scripts
/export/home/conf[naa.909878S4]/FTP = "true"
/export/home/conf[naa.909878S4]/HomeDirs  = "true"
```

I have been trying to get it to work with sed, but have not been getting anywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there aren't any employer IDs with which might be interpreted as valid regular expression characters by `sed`, e.g. `*`, `?` or `\`:

```sh
sed 's:^/export/home/conf\[naa.\('"$(paste -sd '|' employeeid.txt)"'\)\]:#&:' App.conf
```

If you have a lot of employer IDs so that the resulting line becomes too long and your `sed` support `-f-` (otherwise you got to redirect it to a file first and then let `sed` read the script):

```sh
{
  printf '%s' 's:^/export/home/conf\[naa.\(';
  paste -sd '|' employeeid.txt;
  printf '%s' '\)\]:#&:';
} | tr -d '\n' | sed -f- App.conf
```

To make the changes in-place (modifying the file right away instead of showing you the results) add `-i` for GNU `sed` or `-i ''` for FreeBSD `sed`.

Comment: Errh... ok, I had something completely different in mind: turn _each line_ into a regex (instead of concatenating them into a single regex) and escape any special chars in the process e.g. `sed 's|[[\.*^$/]|\\&|g;s|.*|/\\.&\\]/s/^/#/|' employeeid.txt | sed -f- App.conf`... never mind :)...

Answer (score 1):

```
while read employeeid; do
    sed --in-place "/$employeeid/s/^/#/" /path/to/App.conf
done < employeeid.txt
```

Comment: It's worth noting that this would get quite slow with a lot of employer IDs (`read` performance + `sed` runs over the whole file for every employer ID).

Answer (score 1):

***gawk***(GNU awk) approach:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]; next}{match($4, /\[naa\.([0-9A-Z]+)\]/, b); 
     if(b[1] in a) $1="#"$1;}1' OFS="/" employeeid.txt FS="/" App.conf > newfile
```

Now, `newfile` contains the needed lines

---

`a[$1]` - accumulating an array of *employee ids*(as indices) while the first file `employeeid.txt` get processed

`FS="/"` - field separator for the second file `App.conf`

`match($4, /\[naa\.([0-9A-Z]+)\]/, b)` - captures an *employee id* within the **4**th field of a second file's line

`if(b[1] in a) $1="#"$1` - checks if the captured *employee id* is in the *crucial* array. If so, adds `#` to the first field(i.e. at the beginning of the line)

Comment: @ICRealTime, you're welcome